# Create columns from a colum with pattern matching

Tags: r, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have a dataframe with a column of two-digit country codes. Some rows may contain more than one code. Here is a small example with three rows.

```
df <- structure(list(ID =  c("US", "US, US","CA,CA,CA,MX,US,IN")), 
                .Names=c("ID"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = ("data.frame"))
```

I would like to create two columns based on `column ID` as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(ID         = c("US", "US, US","CA,CA,CA,MX,US,JP,IN"), 
                     all_US     = c(1,1,0), 
                     partial_US = c(0,0,1)), 
                     .Names     = c("ID", "all_us", "partial_us"),   row.names = c("1", "2","3"), class = ("data.frame"))
```

`partial_US` is equal to `1` if there is at least one `"US"` in the row.

`all_US`     is equal to `1` if all values are `"US"`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `strsplit()`:

```
df$all_us <- sapply(
  strsplit(df$ID, ", ?"), 
  function(x) all(x == "US")
)
df$partial_us <- sapply(
  strsplit(df$ID, ", ?"), 
  function(x) !all(x == "US") && any(x == "US")
)
                 ID all_us partial_us
1                US   TRUE      FALSE
2            US, US   TRUE      FALSE
3 CA,CA,CA,MX,US,IN  FALSE       TRUE
```

Then if you wan to convert the logical columns to 0/1 you can convert to integer:

```
as.integer(df$all_us)
[1] 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grepl`

```
 df$all_us= +grepl("^(US[, ]*)+$", df$ID)

 df$partial_us = grepl("US",df$ID) - df$all_us
 df
                 ID all_us partial_us
1                US      1          0
2            US, US      1          0
3 CA,CA,CA,MX,US,IN      0          1
```

You can do this as:

```
 transform(df,all_us=a<-+grepl("^(US[, ]*)+$",ID), partial_us = grepl("US", ID) - a)
                 ID all_us partial_us
1                US      1          0
2            US, US      1          0
3 CA,CA,CA,MX,US,IN      0          1
```

Comment: `+` to convert to integer? Wouldn't it be better to simply `as.integer()`? +1 though.

Comment: @snoram its the same thing. you can even decide to multiply by 1 etc or even add 0 or use as.numeric etc

Comment: It's the same things in terms of results but in terms of readability and consistency I would at least avoid it in my own code. ALso `*1` converts to double while "+" converts to integer.

Answer (score 1):

With `strsplit` we `split` the string on "," and check different condition using `if` and `else` and `return` corresponding values accordingly.

```
df[c("all_us", "partial_us")] <- t(sapply(strsplit(df$ID, ","), function(x) {
     if (all(grepl("US", x)))
        return(c(1, 0))
     else if (any(grepl("US", x)))
        return(c(0, 1))
     return(c(0, 0))
}))

df

#                 ID all_us partial_us
#1                US      1          0
#2            US, US      1          0
#3 CA,CA,CA,MX,US,IN      0          1
```

Comment: thanks @Ronak. Are you familiar with this error? Error in `[.data.table`(x, i, which = TRUE) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: @korone the `df` which you have shared is `data.frame` and not `data.table`. The error seems related to `data.table`. Are you sure you have shared the correct structure ?